# Google functions doesn't work turning on and off a vm instance in cloud computing

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I had two Google functions in Google cloud computing to turn on and off an instance. They were working until 2 weeks ago. I cannot find the issue with these functions.

I followed this Medium post https://medium.com/google-cloud/start-stop-compute-engine-instance-from-cloud-function-bf9ae5199609.

Did anything change in Google environment to not allow a cloud function to turn on and off an instance?

The code:

```html
/**
 * Responds to any HTTP request.
 *
 * @param {!express:Request} req HTTP request context.
 * @param {!express:Response} res HTTP response context.
 */

 var http = require('http');
 var Compute = require('@google-cloud/compute');
 var compute = Compute();

exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  var zone = compute.zone('europe-west2-c');    
  var vm = zone.vm('instance-4');    
  vm.start(function(err, operation, apiResponse) {        
    console.log('instance start successfully');
  });
  res.status(200).send('on');
};
```

And in the logs I found:
*Accessing deprecated metadata server endpoint at "/computeMetadata/v1beta1/instance/service-accounts/default/token" from user-agent "google-api-nodejs-client/0.10.0"*

Many thanks!

Comment: Could you check the Google Cloud Functions Logs in your GCP Console. Is there any hint for a error?

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide more information about "the issue" you are having? This could help others to help you resolve your problem.

Comment: It's hard to help you without code and logs! Can you share more?

Comment: I understand that it's been a month already. But have you considered updating your Compute Engine dependency? See latest version here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/compute

Comment: Our app is using Firebase Google Cloud Functions, and our app saw this type of Error from June, 2021